# Create a SharePoint document library with default folders & files

Tags: sharepoint-online

1. Can we create a document library based on document library template using SharePoint REST API or Microsoft Graph? - I guess it is not possible
   P.S. I know we can do it using CSOM/PnP
2. Can we use a Site Script/Site Design to provision a new library based on a template in an existing Modern site.

Answer (score 1):

We can use REST API to create a document library based on the default template 101. If you want to create document library based on custom template using REST API, it seems not works. As you said, we can use CSOM or Pnp to achieve it.

If you want to create a SharePoint document library with default folders & files, we can also use CSOM C# code to add folders and files to the new document library.
Or we can create a document library and add some folders and files, then save the document library as a template(contain contents). And then we can use this template to create new document library.